# Playwright Python - find fillable form by partial placeholder

Tags: css-selectors, pseudo-element, playwright-python

As described in the title, I'm trying to find a fillable field on a webpage whose placeholder contains the word 'name'. Examples of ones I'd like it to select are ones with placeholder text 'First Name' and 'SEARCH BY NAME' and even 'SuRiNaMe' (cause why not). However, everything I've tried with regex and such doesn't appear to be working at all:

```
page.locator("[placeholder=Name]")
page.locator("[placeholder='Name']")
page.locator("[placeholder='/^.*name.*?/']") 
page.locator("[placeholder=/^.*name.*?/]")
```

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath:

```
page.locator("//*[contains(translate(@placeholder, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'name')]")
```

Explaining the xpath:

- `//*`: Any tag element
- `contains`: Contains is a function which receives 2 params (text to check and text that must be contained)
- `translate`: Translate is a function which receives 3 params (The string to evaluate, The string of characters that will be replaced and the string of characters used for replacement

We can say that **our xpath search for any element where the placeholder will be replaced capital letters by lower letters and the result must contain text "name"**

More about xpath functions I used:

- contains: [Contains documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains)
- translate: [Translate documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate)

Comment: Hello! Running that bit of code provides the following error - I'm not quite sure what is wrong with it though, looking at the documentation.
waiting for locator("xpath=//*[contains(lower-case(@placeholder),'name')]")
Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/*[contains(lower-case(@placeholder),'name')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Okay, answer updated. Now it should work

Comment: Thank you so much! The documentation really helps!